# Passing a list of strings to from python/ctypes to C function expecting char **

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a C function which expects a list \0 terminated strings as input:

```
void external_C( int length , const char ** string_list) { 
   // Inspect the content of string_list - but not modify it.
}
```

From python (with ctypes) I would like to call this function based on a list of python strings:

```
def call_c( string_list ):
    lib.external_C( ?? )

call_c( ["String1" , "String2" , "The last string"])
```

Any tips on how to build up the datastructure on the python side? Observe that I guarantee that the C function will NOT alter content of the strings in string_list.

Regards

joakim

Comment: How does the C function know it's reached the end of the sequence of `const char *`?

Comment: Well; in general it does not know of course. My intention was to terminate it with a NULL, alternatively I can pass in a length as well as the (char **) pointer - I have full control over the C library in question.

Joakim

Comment: If it doesn't know, that's pretty useless. You need to tell it somehow, and tell *us* so we can give you code that works.

Comment: OK - OK; I did'nt think that was so important. Anyway I have now changed the definition of the C function so it takes a length argument as the first argument.

Comment: Sorry, what should the argtypes for external_C be?

Answer (score 26):

```
def call_c(L):
    arr = (ctypes.c_char_p * len(L))()
    arr[:] = L
    lib.external_C(len(L), arr)
```

Comment: Notice that in Python 3.x, strings are unicode by default, so you should convert your strings to bytes via `s.encode('utf-8')` or `bytes(s, 'utf-8')` (or whatever encoding you want to use that is not UTF-8).

Comment: It'd be nice to incorporate this ^ into the answer

Answer (score 7):

Thank you very much; that worked like charm. I also did an alternative variation like this:

```
def call_c( L ):
    arr = (ctypes.c_char_p * (len(L) + 1))()
    arr[:-1] = L
    arr[ len(L) ] = None
    lib.external_C( arr )
```

And then in C-function I iterated through the (char **) list until I found a NULL.

Answer (score 6):

## Using ctypes

## create list of expiries( strings)

```
expiries = ["1M", "2M", "3M", "6M","9M", "1Y", "2Y", "3Y","4Y", "5Y", "6Y", "7Y","8Y", "9Y", "10Y", "11Y","12Y", "15Y", "20Y", "25Y", "30Y"]
```

## Logic to send string array

#### convert strings array to bytes array by looping in the array

```
 expiries_bytes = []
    for i in range(len(expiries)):
        expiries_bytes.append(bytes(expiries[i], 'utf-8'))
```

#### Logic ctypes to initiate a pointer with a length of array

```
expiries_array = (ctypes.c_char_p * (len(expiries_bytes)+1))()
```

#### assigning the byte array into the pointer

```
expiries_array[:-1] = expiries_bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

I just make it using SWIG typemap

1.write customized typemap in `demo.i` interface file.

```
%module demo

/* tell SWIG to treat char ** as a list of strings */
%typemap(in) char ** {
    // check if is a list
    if(PyList_Check($input))
    {
        int size = PyList_Size($input);
        int i = 0;
        $1 = (char **)malloc((size + 1)*sizeof(char *));
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            PyObject * o = PyList_GetItem($input, i);
            if(PyString_Check(o))
                $1[i] = PyString_AsString(o);
            else
            {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "list must contain strings");
                free($1);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "not a list");
        return NULL;
    }
}

// clean up the char ** array
%typemap(freearg) char ** {
    free((char *) $1);
}
```

2.generate extension

```
$ swig -python demo.i  // generate wrap code
$ gcc -c -fpic demo.c demo_wrap.c
$ gcc -shared demo.o demo_wrap.o -o _demo.so
```

3.import the module in python.

```
>>> from demo import yourfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to pass a *list of int*/ a *list of string* / *string* / *float* to c code

```py
import ctypes

clib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("main.o")

# Pass a list of int
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr = (ctypes.c_int * len(L))()
arr[:] = L

# Pass a list of string
str_lst = ["hello", "world", "!", "\0"]
str_arr = (ctypes.c_char_p * len(str_lst))()
str_arr[:] = [i.encode("utf-8") for i in str_lst]

x = clib.my_c_fun(1
                  , ctypes.c_float(1.2)
                  , ctypes.c_char_p("hello".encode('utf-8'))
                  , arr
                  , str_arr
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but I think worth to add if people still search for similar question.

using numpy, would be probably easiest way for handling all the low level manipulations and linking with with libraries.

```
example = ["String1" , "String2" , "The last string"]
example_np = m = np.array(example, dtype=np.chararray)
```

when you build you numpy array of char*, you could just get the pointer to array (with ctypes and directly give it to the lib expecting char**.

```
example_ptr = ctypes.cast(example_np.ctypes.data, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)) # this is char**
```

and you could just call

```
lib.external_C(len(example), example_ptr)
```