# Wrapping a C function call taking char** [in/out], to return a python list in cython

Tags: c++, python, arrays, cython

**How do you wrap a C function call that expects a pre-allocated `char**` as an argument to store the result? I am trying to return a python list result.**

I have found examples of the other way around, and also [this ctypes example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494598/passing-a-list-of-strings-to-from-python-ctypes-to-c-function-expecting-char), but I am not entirely sure ctypes is the appropriate approach in cython.

For reference, I am practicing wrapping the [openni](http://www.openni.org) library:
http://openni.org/Documentation/Reference/classxn_1_1_pose_detection_capability.html

The original C signature I am wrapping is (its actually a C++ method that just wraps around a C function internally):

```
/**
 * @brief Gets the names of all poses supported by this capability.

 * @param [out]     pstrPoses   Pre-allocated memory for the names of the supported poses.
 * @param [in,out]  nPoses      In input - size of the preallocated memory, in output
 *                              - the number of pose names.
 */

XnStatus GetAvailablePoses(XnChar** pstrPoses, XnUInt32& nPoses) const
```

(`XnChar` is just a typedef for `char`)

Here is my attempt so far, which crashes:

```py
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

def get_available_poses(self):
    cdef: 
        int i 
        bytes name 
        XnStatus stat
        XnUInt32 size = self.handle.GetNumberOfPoses()
        XnChar **buf = <XnChar**>malloc(size * sizeof(XnChar*))

    if not buf:
        raise MemoryError()

    try:
        # this crashes: Segmentation fault
        stat = self.handle.GetAvailablePoses(buf, size)

        # if I could get to here, I would want to 
        # build a list to return (not saying this is
            # even correct either)
        for i in range(size):
            name = <char*>(buf[i])
            ...

    finally:
        free(buf)
```

That version of the C function is technically deprecated, but the newer one looks even scarier to me:

```
/**
 * Gets the names of all poses supported by this capability.

 * @param [out]     pstrPoses       Pre-allocated memory for the names of the supported poses.
 * @param [in]      nNameLength     Memory size for each pose name.
 * @param [in,out]  nPoses          In input - size of the preallocated memory, in output
 *                                  - the number of pose names.
 */

 XnStatus GetAllAvailablePoses(XnChar** pstrPoses, XnUInt32 nNameLength, 
                                XnUInt32& nPoses) const;
```

Ideally if I could figure out how to pass in a proper `char**` and produce a list, I would use the newer one that also requires me to specify the length of the names that was allocated.

**Update**:

I simplified this problem down to just the basics to make sure I am doing this right in the first place:

src:

```
//chars.h

void setChars(char** str_array, int size);

//chars.cc

#include "chars.h"

void setChars(char** str_array, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char *s = "FOO";
        str_array[i] = s;
    }
}
```

cython:

```
#chars.pxd

cdef extern from "chars.h":
    void setChars(char**, int)

#chars.pyx

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

def py_setChars():
    cdef: 
        bytes s
        int i
        int size = 6
        char** buf = <char**>malloc(size * sizeof(char*))

    if not buf:
        raise MemoryError()

    out = []

    try:
        setChars(buf, size)

        for i in range(size):
            s = buf[i]
            out.append(s)

    finally:
        free(buf)

    return out
```

And it works as expected:

```
In [1]: import chars
In [2]: chars.py_setChars()
Out[2]: ['FOO', 'FOO', 'FOO', 'FOO', 'FOO', 'FOO']
```

I am guessing the `GetAllAvailablePoses()` call I want to use is expecting some kind of pre-allocated memory that I am not doing right, hence the param asking for the size of each char.

Comment: Are you sure you're pre-allocating the right thing? It just wants a pre-allocated array of uninitialized `char*`s, not, say, a pre-allocated array of a bunch of `char*`s pointing at pre-allocated string buffers? Or even just an array of NULL-initialized `char*`s? (Also, since you're apparently trying to wrap some library that you didn't write, maybe you want to tell us which one so we can look at the docs.)

Comment: are you sure that's crashing where you think it's crashing?  It looks to me like name = <char*>(buf[i]) comes after free(buf).

Comment: @abarnert: I am actually not sure of anything which is why I'm causing a crash :-)  This is one example of a couple approaches I have tried with no luck. But I just updated the question with the openni doc reference.

Comment: @user237182: Whoops! That was a mis-paste from a mix of things that were commented out. I just moved that block into the try. But I am 100% sure its the `GetAvailablePoses` causing the crash because I can return before that location in the code and it does not crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out with enough playing. `GetAllAvailablePoses` really does expect you to preallocate the space of each `char*` and tell it how big that space is for it to populate:

```
# foo.pxd

XnStatus GetAllAvailablePoses(XnChar **, XnUInt32, XnUInt32&)

# foo.pyx

def get_available_poses(self):
    cdef: 
        int i 
        bytes name 
        XnStatus stat
        XnUInt32 nameLength = 256
        XnUInt32 size = self.handle.GetNumberOfPoses()

    cdef XnChar **buf = <XnChar**>malloc(size * sizeof(XnChar*))

    if not buf:
        raise MemoryError()

    for i in range(size):
        buf[i] = <XnChar*>malloc(nameLength)

    out = [None]*size

    try:
        stat = self.handle.GetAllAvailablePoses(buf, nameLength, size)

        for i in range(size):
            name = <char*>buf[i]
            out[i] = name

    finally:
        free(buf)

    return out

# Out: ['Psi', 'CrossHandsPose', 'Wave', 'Click', 'RaiseHand', 'MovingHand']
```

Comment: From looking at the links you gave… I think you want to file a documentation bug against that function. It very clearly says a pointer to pre-allocated memory, not a pointer to a pre-allocated array of pointers to pre-allocated memory. And, with no examples, your confusion is exactly what they should have expected. Anyway, glad you worked it out.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for the support! It's probably more confusing for a person trying to learn cython with almost no C++ experience. Though what do you say about the fact that they ask for a `nameLength` value stating how much memory has been allocated for each `char*`? It seems to me like what they want is just the space to fill with char data.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that seems reasonable. Someone with enough experience with both the C++ language and C-style APIs may well have gotten it right by the second or third guess… but still, not ideal as documentation goes. I'm sure you're not the only one who's ever been confused by it.