# Pass Mutable String Array From Python to C

Tags: python, c, string, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am new to both C and ctypes, but I cannot seem to find an answer on how to do this, particularly with a numpy array.

**C Code**

```
// Import/Export Macros
#define DllImport   __declspec( dllimport )
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )

// Test function for receiving and transmitting arrays
extern "C"
DllExport void c_fun(char **string_array)
{
    string_array[0] = "foo";
    string_array[1] = "bar";
    string_array[2] = "baz";
}
```

**Python Code**

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes

# Load the DLL library...

# Define function argtypes
lib.c_fun.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(ctypes.c_char, ndim = 2, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS")]

# Initialize, call, and print
string_array = np.empty((3,10),dtype=ctypes.c_char)
lib.c_fun(string_array)
print(string_array)
```

I am sure there is some encoding/decoding that needs to happen as well, but I am not sure how/which. Thanks!

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3494857/645128)  It address arrays of strings, but you should be able to adapt to your need.

Comment: C Code is incorrect. You cannot assign string literals if a char pointer is expected. The literals foo, bar, baz are normally placed in a r/o segment, so they cannot be modified (In python speech they are not mutable). However, string_array is declared as a double pointer to non-const (mutable) C strings. This does not work. Either declare string_array as `const char**` or add memory allocation and strcpy the literals. I think, you may want latter. In either case you additionally need to reserve space for the list of pointers to the strings. Mind the char ** is a ptr to a ptr to char.

Comment: @ryyker I did see that solution, but have seen others that say initializing the character array in such a way is slow, so I was hoping to use numpy

Comment: @pqans Thanks for the information. I have tried to avoid using memory allocation within the C code, as per my understanding, the caller should manage the memory to avoid leakage. I have changed the C code to expect `const char **string_array` and am using strcpy, but receiving a compilation error "'char *strcpy(char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *'"

Comment: Are you able to change the prototype to the DLL function?  `DllExport void c_fun(char **string_array)`

Comment: You can do anything in C even if it messes sth up. You can attempt to write to a r/o segment and risk an exception, if you want to. Especially in embedded environments the differentiation between r/o and r/w segments may not be such strict. However that does not mean one should rely on that.

Comment: No, it is u.b. if you cast away the const. The cast is sane only, if the original string is not const but for some reason regarded as const. If the original string is const and you cast away that const you may write to memory where it is not allowed.

Comment: @pqans - you are right, it is UB.  I have deleted those comments.

Answer (score 1):

*Addressing the `C` code part of the question only*...

As noted in comments, `C` does not allow assignments in this way *if* the three variables shown are defined as `char` arrays:

```
string_array[0] = "foo";
string_array[1] = "bar";
string_array[2] = "baz";
```

Use the following:

```
strcpy(string_array[0], "foo");
strcpy(string_array[1], "bar");
strcpy(string_array[2], "baz");
```

And as long as the caller to this function is pre-allocating *and* freeing memory for the buffers, this part of the solution is now at least syntactically correct.

***But*** *if the strings do indeed need to be immutable* to be compatible with Python, then in the caller function allocate memory to create `char **string_array` such that you can pass an *array of 3 pointers* as the argument.  For example:

```
char **string_array = malloc(3*sizeof(*string_array));//creates array of 3 pointers.
```

Then call it as:

```
c_fun(string_array);
```

This allows use of the DLL call just as shown in in your original post.:

```
DllExport void c_fun(char **string_array)
{
    //array of pointers being assigned to addresses of 3 string literals
    string_array[0] = "foo";//these will now be immutable strings
    string_array[1] = "bar";
    string_array[2] = "baz";
}
```